# Source for rumored ruling of the Chafetz Chaim regarding Bracha on dessert

Tags: halacha, blessing, food, chofetz-chaim

[The Laws of Brachos](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9780899062204.html) by Rabbi Binyamin Forst says the following on page 211 note 16.

> "Rumor has it that the Chafetz Chaim allegedly said, that in America,
>   desserts are part of the meal and require no Bracha."

He says that based on the [Shaar Hatzion 7 on Mishna Berura Orach Chaim 177:1:4](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=49624&st=&pgnum=153) this rumor should be laid to rest.

Is there any further source to this rumor?

Comment: Just to make this story more bizarre and less believable, one of my Rebbeim told me that the way it was presented to him was that Reb Moshe Feinstein as a young man met the Chafetz Chaim and presented this argument to him and the Chafetz Chaim agreed. On the flip side though, since when can't someone retract from an earlier opinion? Besides, there are quite a few halachas tgat have come down from Rabbi Zacks and others from the Ch.Ch. which contradict what is written in the M.B. (which some have claimed was not exclusively written by the Ch.Ch.).

Comment: @user6591: The question then remains which ruling was earlier?

Comment: This of course is of no practical halachic significance as dessert nowadays may be a totally different animal as it was 100 years ago. The ChCh's evaluation of American dessert patterns from 100 years ago need not mach patterns today. One should always ask a Poseik who is familiar with current dessert patterns.

Comment: @DoubleAA: I would think that if the Chafetz Chaim said so 100 years ago it would be more so today.

Comment: @GershonGold I have no idea as I dont know what dessert patterns were like 100 years ago in the USA or in Poland to compare to. Do you?

Comment: @Gershon The second chelek of Mishna Berurah was printed nine years before Reb Moshe was born. So I think we know which came first:)

Comment: @DoubleAA: Do not know exactly what dessert patterns were 100 years ago, however it is definitely more part of a meal today.

Comment: @GershonGold, how do you figure?

Comment: @SethJ: We eat way more food than 100 years ago, and dessert is expected by all formal meals.

Comment: @GershonGold, do you clear the table?  Why is its expectation relevant? Isn't the issue satiation?

Comment: @SethJ: I have seen many people finish eating dessert and going on to continue eating.

Comment: @gershon that sounds pretty gross.

Answer (score 3):

[Rabbi Daniel Neustadt](http://www.torah.org/advanced/weekly-halacha/5760/naso.html) says the following in note 3 of Weekly Halacha

> Several sources report that the Chafetz Chayim eventually changed his
>   ruling and exempted cooked fruits served as dessert from a blessing;
>   see Orchos Rabbeinu 66 and Vezos ha-Berachah, pg. 78. [Others dispute
>   that the Chafetz Chayim changed his ruling.] Reportedly, Harav A.
>   Kotler ruled that no blessing is recited over cooked fruit.